# Google maps api - open first infoWindow

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Here is a code of adding infoWindows and markers on google map:

```
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()
    createMarker = (company)->
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(company.latitude, company.longitude),
        map: map,
        title: company.name
      })

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', ()->
        content = 'some content'
        infowindow.setContent(content)
        infowindow.open(map,this)
      )

    createMarker(data[i]) for i in [0..data.length-1] by 1
```

I need to open first infoWindow automaticaly after page is loaded. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fire an event:
    google.maps.event.trigger(, 'click');

Now, you'll need to store the references to the "marker" variables. Change

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
```

for

```
company.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
```

and add a last line:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(data[0].marker, 'click');
```